# Java resident memory growing when Executors.newCachedThreadPool used

Tags: java, threadpool, executorservice

I am using `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()` to process client api requests. It seems that resident memory of the java process grows with time when average 10tps traffic and it does not get decreased. In addition when looking at thread id, it also shows that threads are not reused. Is there any solution for this. I am using Java 7.

Comment: Maybe threads are not reused because the actual task that is executed is not finished so the thread is not returned to the pool? Without getting more information we can only guess.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Any ideal threads will be reaped after 60 seconds of sitting idle. If you submit any new task during that time, the thread will be reused. Please provide some more data.

Comment: Each thread in the pool sends a message to activemq and it seems that after removing activemq message send functionality, memory does not grow and threads are reused.

Comment: its may be due to long running task and for long running task cached pool is not recommended

Answer (score 0):

I would record when a task is started and finished as it seems you have an increasing number of threads. I would try using a relatively small fixed size pool instead to ensure they are reused and it will show if you have a bug causing a resource leak.

I would also consider using a recent version of Java such as 8 or 11 though I didn't think it would make a difference in this case.